# Google Chrome not loading sections of webpage until rollover?

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome, webkit

I have been using Big Cartel's store platform to make a webpage and online store for my friends business. However, whenever I load my webpage in Google Chrome it doesn't load the buttons and text until I rollover them. It works fine with Mozilla Firefox and ie but funnily, not with Firefox. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QiwiC.png) is how the page should look in Firefox but in Chrome it looks like [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYgYi.png)
. How should I fix his issue? The website is [Vained](http://www.vained.co.uk) and I am using the [Rivington](http://themefiend.com/theme/rivington/) theme. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I see them in Chrome 33

Comment: Is isn't for me, unless I rollover them first. Then they appear.

Comment: I'd suggest you add more details to your question, e.g. what version of Chrome you are using, on what OS.
Also try clearing your cache.

Comment: I've run in to a similar issue with both your site and the one I'm working with;  Chrome version `33.0.1750.154 m` and also within a `<ul>` (in my case it's `<ul><li><a><i></i></a></li></ul>` structure and it's all of the <i> elements which aren't rendering.  Perhaps an issue with anchors in list items for this version of Chrome?